# Column Indexing and DELETE query performance

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, performance, indexing

I have a table with few Columns like ID (PK), Name, created_time etc. and periodically I DELETE rows from this table by using this simple DELETE query.

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE created_time < 'some time';
```

Just want to know what will be the performance impact on `INSERT`, `SELECT` and `DELETE` if I make or not make an `INDEX` on `created_time`.

This table may have millions of rows and one `DELETE` query may delete rows in hundred thousands in one go.

Database : Oracle, JavaDB, DB2, SQL Server

Comment: I would really look into the date-based partitioning in your case.

Comment: It would slow down inserts very slightly (probably not even noticeable), it would improve selects and deletes that use the index...

Comment: For SQL Server, consider putting the clustered index on `created_time` rather than (as is probably now the case) `ID`. This will pay dividends particularly if this is some kind of fact table with historical data and almost all queries include `created_time` to limit their results. (Oracle doesn't have clustered indexes, the index design would be different there.)

Comment: @Jeroen , this table has very high number of INSERT / bulk INSERT (100s to 1000s every minute), very low number of SELECT (not necessary on created_time col) and fix hourly DELETE

Comment: Then putting the clustered index on `created_time` can still pay off because the `DELETE` can delete a range of rows in a clustered index seek, which is faster than with a ton of index lookups. I assume rows are inserted in chronological order, otherwise it's not a good pick for the clustered index.

Comment: Thankyou Jeroen. yes, created_time is the row insertion time. Also there is another column something like KEY1 which have only 10-20 possible different values and I may have include this KEY1 column to SELECT and DELETE rows, do you think adding this KEY1 column in INDEX will also improve DELETE and SELECT without compromising with INSERT performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you make an INDEX on created_time.
1. Insert it will slow because it need to check column created_time is one time only(like a key).
2. SELECT and DELETE will quick if your condition where WHERE created_time = 'some time' It's mean if it find the first row of condition it will stop.

Comment: created_time is not a unique column hence same value may exists multiple time.